Creating a loft surface using Autocad .net API
I am trying to create a loft surface using a list of spline entities
These splines are created using a geographical 3D coordinates
My code is working perfectly fine (check the code in the snap )
enter image description here
This is how I am creating surface in AutoCAD 2024(check snap)
enter image description here
The above surface consists of around 25 splines each of length 745 units
using all these splines I am creating a loft surface
but when I am trying to create a loft surface on clients model
I am facing performance issues with AutoCAD
The client model consists of around 200 splines each of length 15000 units
Even after waiting for around half an hour the surface is not being created on client's model
Is there any other method to create a loft surface in AutoCAD other than CreateLoftedSurface() method that would help to create a surface with large no.of splines and with each spline having length of around 15000 units without affecting the performance.
It would be great if anyone can help me with the issue.
Thanks in advance....!!!
